# What formula will tell if three vertices in 3d space are ordered clockwise or counter-clockwise from the point of view of a camera?

Tags: geometry, 3d

Assuming 3 ordered vertices in 3d space and a camera looking toward those points. What formula will tell me if they are seen clockwise or counter-clockwise in relation to their order?

Comment: Take two consecutive edges of that triangle. Calculate their cross product. The cross product either points away from or towards the camera (compute the inner product with the line of sight - its sign gives you the answer, but I don't remember which is which). The key is that the cross product gives the normal to the plane of that triangle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the camera is at the origin, consider the $3\times 3$ matrix with column vectors equal to the three point vectors. The sign of the determinant of this matrix tells you the orientation.

Comment: I tried it without success. Maybe there is something I am doing wrong? I created 3 points by subtracting the three original point with the camera's position, created a matrix as you said, but what happens is that it will only work if my camera if on a specific side of the plane defined by the three points. Else, the result will be the inverse of what it is supposed to be.

Comment: Your method is right, I'm sorry. My problem is somewhere else now, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Call the three points $p_1,p_2,p_3$, and assume the camera is located at the origin. One thing you could do is define $$N:=(p_2-p_1)\times(p_3-p_2),$$ where $\times$ denotes cross product, and then calculate $$S:=N\cdot p_1\quad.$$ If the plane spanned by the three points passes through the origin, you will get $S=0.$ Otherwise, the sign of $S$ will answer your question.

Comment: I tried but but without success. Maybe there is something I am doing wrong? I get p1, p2 and p3 by subtracting my three original points to the position of the camera, then I multiply (p2 - p1) and (p3 - p2). At this point, I tried both normalizing N and not normalizing it. After this, I calculate the dot product of N and p1 but I get strange results. S will sometimes be positive, sometimes negative depending of the angle formed by p2 p1 p3 even when the camera is at the same position and p1 p2 p3 are alligned along the same plane.